# Reading and re-writing specific lines on TCL

Tags: tcl

Dears, I have the following information (x y z) in a "data.dat" file:

```
24.441 53.481 41.474
23.920 53.389 42.572
24.470 52.228 42.012
24.875 51.313 42.524
23.663 51.323 42.701
```

I require to re-write the information as following:

```
{24.441 53.481 41.474} {23.920 53.389 42.572}
{23.920 53.389 42.572} {24.470 52.228 42.012}
{24.470 52.228 42.012} {24.875 51.313 42.524}
{24.875 51.313 42.524} {23.663 51.323 42.701}
```

This is for a large data file. How could I do that in TCL. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
set infile  "data.dat"
set outfile [file tempfile]

set in  [open $infile r]
set out [open $outfile w]

gets $in prev_line
while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
    puts $out [format "{%s} {%s}" $prev_line $line]
    set prev_line $line
}

close $in
close $out

# remove next line if you don't need to keep a backup of the initial file
file link -hard "${infile}.bak" $infile

# and overwrite the original file with the new contents
file rename -force $outfile $infile
```

or, call out to GNU awk to do it

```
exec gawk -i inplace {
    NR == 1 {prev = $0; next}
    {printf "{%s} {%s}\n", prev, $0; prev = $0}
} data.dat
```

Comment: You might wonder if you can edit data in place. Technically yes, but it's dangerous (with any programming language) if the data changes the length of any line. It's ___much___ easier to get a write to a separate file correct.